# Country Outliers

Tags: mathematics, word, pattern, language, english

You are given a note from a language nerd, which is:

> If Japan is 239,
>
> Then Germany is 4.
>
> Greece is 14,
>
> While Italy is 3.
>
> Now, Philippines has 412.
>
> But Norway has 2357!

Now you are given 3 questions:

> 1. Which of these numbers that satisfy this country: Afghanistan?
>
> h) 78 b) 4 c) 2 r) 15
>
> 2. What does Wales have?
>
> a) 36 e) 872 o) 28 u) 8
>
> 3. What country has this number: 5?
>
> g) Sweden t) Lithuania y) Estonia d) Romania

Here is the last note, which says:

> Take the letters you just answered at the second note. It should be a valid word.

**Question:** How does the formula work, and what is the word?

Hint 1:

> Numbers and Languages do exist.

Hint 2: (big)

> Take the number 4. Do you see any rule that this number has, but no number has it except this?

Last Hint:

> 1, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, and so on... also 18, 8, 5, 4, 4, and so on... See? It esclates quick.

Comment: Are you deliberately distinguishing between _having_ a number and _being_ a number? (E.g., you say Germany is 4 but the Philippines have 412.)

Comment: is Wales separate county?

Comment: The simplest formula mostly works but I don't understand the 9 in J or why N has 57 instead of 4. So will need another hint.

Comment: Or are you sure the values are correct?

Answer (score 2):

**Hints**

I understand the meaning of the hints:

> in English, **four** is the only number which has the same number of letters as the number itself; for other numbers, we can apply a process of counting letters to get sequences like *eighteen, eight, five, four, four, four, ...* or *one, three, five, four, four, four, ...*

---

**Puzzle structure**

My guess is that the puzzle involves

> numbers which have the same property that "four" has in English, but in different languages.

Supporting this is the fact that

> 4 in German is **vier** with 4 letters, and 3 in Italian is **tre** with 3 letters.

But I'm not sure what to do for the numbers with more than one digit: for example,

> 14 in Greek doesn't have 14 letters, and 1 and 4 in Greek don't have 1, 4, or 14 letters.

On the other hand,

> 1 in Greek does have 4 letters ... but 2 in Norwegian doesn't have 3 letters, nor does 2 in Japanese have 3 letters.

**Answers**

At least I can partially answer the third question:

> 5 in Swedish and Estonian doesn't have 5 letters, but in Lithuanian and Romanian it does. So the answer is either **t** or **d**.

And the first question:

> 2 in the Dari language of Afghanistan has 2 letters, so the answer is probably **c**.

For the second question, I'm mostly reduced to figuring it out from the letters:

> 8 in Welsh doesn't have 8 letters, so it's *not* u. Then, to form a word of the form **c?t** or **c?d**, the most likely option is probably **cat**, although it could be *cad* or *cot* or *cod* in theory.

So I think the answers are

> 1c, 2a, 3t,

but I'm not fully sure of the logic.

Comment: rot13(Terrx vf abg gur bayl ynathntr va Terrpr, gubhtu. Va Nyonavna, 14 unf 14 yrggref. Ohg gung fgvyy qbrfa'g rkcynva gur >100 ahzoref gubhtu.)

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this pattern, which probably is not the desired answer but it's worth sharing anyway.

From [Rand al'Thor's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/109222/73282):

> The  hints are mainly about that special property of the number 4 in English, being the only one made of a number of letters equal to itself.
>  Italy and Germany are the only two countries in the text of the riddle in which the number they are being paired with has that same special property (in Italian 3 is **tre** and in German 4 is **vier**).

Now I noticed that if you order the countries by their given number:

> you are also ordering them by the number of islands in the country, except for Italy and Germany:
>  <s>Italy</s> 3 [450 islands](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+many+islands+in+italy&oq=how+many+islands+in+italy&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i22i30l7j0i390l2.7647j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
>  <s>Germany</s> 4 [50 islands](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+many+islands+in+germany&sxsrf=ALeKk01S_5mJT7pdIzDY5r4vBmZMOwHBVw%3A1617909760089&ei=AFhvYMnrBJPygQbgx4WIBA&oq=how+many+islands+in+germ&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMYADIECCMQJzoHCAAQRxCwAzoHCAAQsAMQQzoKCC4QsAMQyAMQQzoGCAAQFhAeOgIIADoHCAAQhwIQFDoICAAQFhAKEB5KBQg4EgExUOiGAVjUmAFg_KABaAFwAngAgAFviAHQBZIBAzguMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQ7AAQE&sclient=gws-wiz)
>  Greece 14 [6000 islands](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+many+islands+in+greece&oq=how+many+islands+in+greece&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i22i30l7j0i390.6038j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
>  Japan 239 [7000 islands](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+many+islands+in+japan&oq=how+many+islands+in+japan&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3j0i22i30l6.7004j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
>  Philippines 412 [7640 islands](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+many+islands+in+the+philippines&oq=how+many+islands+in+the+philippines&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l9.10865j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
>  Norway 2357 [50000 islands](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+many+islands+in+norway&sxsrf=ALeKk01HMByDyqxt7R_hGnr9oq6FJt2iwA%3A1617907446244&ei=9k5vYICgDr397_UPqLuhwAc&oq=how+many+islands+in+nor&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMYADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjoHCAAQRxCwAzoHCAAQsAMQQzoKCC4QsAMQyAMQQzoECCMQJ0oFCDgSATFQwe4DWJODBGCrjARoAXACeACAAVmIAZcFkgECMTCYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6yAELwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz)
>
>  We assume that it's fine to ignore Italy and Germany because their number has the special property mentioned above.

So with this logic we can answer the **first question** with:

> **c)** because Afghanistan has no islands, so it should be paired with a number that is less than the 14 of Greece. And **2** is the only possible answer.
>  I also checked whether 2 in the Afghanistan's Pashto language is made of two letters, and [I believe it's not](https://translate.google.com/?hl=en&sl=auto&tl=ps&text=two&op=translate).

The answer to the **second question** would be:

> **u)** because Wales has [100 islands](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk02YknIV1Ev3UFIXZKJ1eY_cDUFYBw:1617907644406&q=how+many+islands+in+wales&spell=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj5hbLTp-_vAhViTBUIHVudCzsQBSgAegQIARAw&biw=1294&bih=669) and thus should get a number between the 2 of Afghanistan and the 14 of Greece. Here **8** is the only possible answer and in Welsh is **wyth** (not made of eight letters).

Answer to the **Third question**:

> We got to pair **5** with some country. In our ordered list, 5 would fit between 2, corresponding to zero islands, and 8, corresponding to 100 islands. There are two possibilities here: Lithuania and Romania (Sweden and Estonia have more than 100 islands).
>  Now in both Romanian and Lithuanian 5 has five letters. I found that 7 in Lithuanian has [seven letters](https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=lt&text=seven&op=translate&hl=en) so 5 doesn't have this unique property in Lithuanian and the answer should be **d) Romania**.

So the *valid* word is:

> **cud**

...whatever it means.